# Alternating Color & Cell Specific Color in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to have both an alternating color for rows in a Tablix SSRS 2008 R2 + overriding the color by another expression on specific cells?

I was able to color cells alone and rows alone, but not have both. Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example, just extending the logic in the `BackgroundColor` property with some nested `IIf` functions. I've used the expression:

```
=IIf(Fields!val.Value = 3
    , "Red"
    ,IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "LightGrey", "LightSteelBlue")
)
```

Which give the results:

[image]

Comment: Ian, you add this code to a row or cell? Most probably row right?

Comment: As far as my testing goes, when you're doing something like this you're *always* adding it to the cell level. Even when you're selecting a row and updating the *BackgroundColor* property, all the editor is doing is setting the *BackgroundColor* property for all cells in the row. If all cells in the row have the same *BackgroundColor*, it will show the same value at the row level, but if they are different, e.g. the above screenshot, *BackgroundColor* will be blank at the row level.